# Breaking lines in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, grass-gis, intersection, table, road

I have a roads table and I want to break the lines in the intersections like the [v.clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.clean.html) tool from GRASS (I'm talking about how the **break** tool in the parameters works).

How can I do the same process in PostGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [ST_PointN](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PointN.html) and [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html).

[image]

You could look through tutorial here from @Paul Ramsey [Breaking a Linestring into Segments](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/breaking-linestring-into-segments.html)

```
CREATE TABLE lines ( 
  gid integer primary key, 
  geom geometry(Linestring, 4326)
);

INSERT INTO lines VALUES (1, 'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4)');
INSERT INTO lines VALUES (2, 'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(0 1, 0 2, 0 3, 0 4)');

WITH 
dumps AS ( 
  SELECT gid, ST_DumpPoints(geom) AS pt FROM lines
), 
pts AS (
  SELECT gid, (pt).geom, (pt).path[1] AS vert FROM dumps
) 
SELECT a.gid, ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[a.geom, b.geom])) AS geom, 
       a.vert, b.vert 
FROM pts a, pts b 
WHERE a.gid = b.gid AND a.vert = b.vert-1 AND b.vert > 1;

-- High performance alternative
WITH segments AS (
SELECT gid, ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(lag((pt).geom, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY gid ORDER BY gid, (pt).path), (pt).geom)) AS geom
  FROM (SELECT gid, ST_DumpPoints(geom) AS pt FROM lines) as dumps
)
SELECT * FROM segments WHERE geom IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ST_Node](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Node.html) for this.  It will node geometries on intersections but note the comment in the docs that you should use Geos 3.3.2 or higher (and PostGIS 2.x).